# .htaccess single variable url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect http://test.pearlsquirrel.com/explore_all?u=hiphop to http://test.pearlsquirrel.com/explore_all/hiphop using htaccess.  However, It keeps redirecting here: http://test.pearlsquirrel.com/explore_all/?u=site_error.php.  I have looked all over Stackoverflow for the answer but I just can't seem to find it.  I would really appreciate some help in fixing this problem, thanks!

Here is my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.pearlsquirrel.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pearlsquirrel.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) explore_all?u=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  [^=]+=([^=]+)
RewriteRule .* /%1? [L]
```

Will map this:

`http://test.pearlsquirrel.com/explore_all?u=hiphop`

To this:

`http://test.pearlsquirrel.com/explore_all/hiphop`

Replace the corresponding code in your .htaccess file with this one.

I have not checked the rules in your .htaccess file.

**OPTION**

Now, if it is the other way around, which I think it is, and the idea is to map this incoming URL:

`http://test.pearlsquirrel.com/explore_all/hiphop`

To this resource:

`http://test.pearlsquirrel.com/explore_all?u=hiphop`

Replace the above rule set with this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  .*/([^/]+)/?
RewriteRule .* http://test.pearlsquirrel.com/explore_all?u=%1 [L]
```

Comment: This still does not seem to sovve the problem.  i get a 404 not found error when I try to go to the link http://test.pearlsquirrel.com/explore_all/hiphop.

Comment: ¿Does `/hiphop` directory exists? You say: `http://test.pearlsquirrel.com/explore_all?u=hiphop` to `http://test.pearlsquirrel.com/explore_all/hiphop`, I think it should be the other way around. The URL shown in the browser address bar should be this one: `http://test.pearlsquirrel.com/explore_all/hiphop` not the first one, but I just answered your question. If so, update your question and I will gladly update my answer.

Comment: The directory does not exist.  Should the directory exist?  Sorry for any confusion that this has caused.

Comment: Look my previous comment. I think what you want is the opposite of what you asked. I will update the answer.